# How to get form errors in Symfony as JSON-object with JMSSerializer

Tags: json, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, jmsserializerbundle

I need to have a generic JSON-representation of errors for any form that I have.

I have already read other solutions like in [how to return json encoded form errors in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556121/how-to-return-json-encoded-form-errors-in-symfony). But I don't want to create one more service for task that is already can be solved by other bundle that I connected to my project.

I use `JMSSerializerBundle` in my project and I know that this bundle can handle Symfony form errors using `FormErrorHandler`. But now I can get only whole form serialization:

```
$errors = $form->getErrors();
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$json = $serializer->serialize($errors, 'json');
```

This code will return me next JSON-object:

```
{
    "form": {
        "children": {
            "field1": [],
            "field2": [],
            "field_with_error": {
                "errors": ["Error text"]
            },
            "collection": {
                "child_form": [
                    {
                        "children": {
                            "field1": [],
                            "field2": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "errors": []
}
```

But I need something like that (only fields with errors):

```
{
    "field_with_error": {
        "errors": ["Error text"]
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that? I looked at FOSRestBundle that has already solved this problem. But I didn't find how they did it.

Comment: Have a look at this : [JMSSerializer + forms/arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455823/jmsserializer-forms-arrays?rq=1). You might have to write your own handler to "flatten" the array : [Subscribing Handlers](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers)

Comment: I know what I can. But I want to use solution that is already in JMSSerializerBundle (`FormErrorHandler`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using following code you can get errors the same structure you want:

```
$handler = new FormErrorHandler($this->get('translator'));
$visitor = new JsonSerializationVisitor(new SerializedNameAnnotationStrategy(new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()));
$errors = json_encode($handler->serializeFormToJson($visitor, $editForm, array()));
```

**Result**

```
"{"children":{"title":{"errors":["This value should not be blank."]},"summary":{"errors":["Give your post a summary!"]},"content":{"errors":["Your post should have some content!"]}}}"
```

Comment: This gives exactly the same output for me (`jms/serializer 1.1.0` & `SF 3.1.0`)